# jQuery: How do you pass $(this) as function parameter?

Tags: jquery

All jQuery examples I see has in-line functions.

If the function is pretty long, or if the function is reusable, I may want to separate the function.

For example, how can I turn this

```
$('#myElement').click(function(){
  $(this).addCss('clicked');
})
```

into something like this

```
$('#myElement').click(ElementClicked($(this))

function ElementClicked(???){
  ???.addCss('clicked');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This won't work:

```
$('#myElement').click(ElementClicked($(this)));
```

This is executing the function `ElementClicked()` with whatever `this` is at the time of writing, and binds the **return value** of `ElementClicked()` to the `click` event. Which in this case is nothing.

You'll need to *pass* a function to a click event, like so:

```
$('#myElement').click(function () { ElementClicked($(this)); });
```

This makes a(n anonymous) function, which will be bound to the `click` event, and the function calls `ElementClicked()` when run, passing `this`. The function `ElementClicked` can be defined as:

```
function ElementClicked(elem) {
  elem.addClass('clicked');
}
```

As you will notice though, `this` inside the function that is bound to the event will be the clicked element. So instead of making a function wrapper that calls a function passing the element, you can just abbreviate it like so:

```
$('#myElement').click(ElementClicked);

function ElementClicked() {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
}
```

Notice that the function is passed to `click()` like a variable instead of being executed immediately, because there are no brackets `()` following it.

And BTW, you probably mean `addClass` instead of `addCss`.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an expression; you pass it just like you'd pass `(x + 1)` or whatever. Give it a name in your function and you're good to go:

```
function elementClicked(banana) {
    banana.addClass('clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myElement').click(function(){
  ElementClicked($(this)); 
})

function ElementClicked(el){
  el.addCss('clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to seperate  between

> document.elementByID("div1")
>
> $("#div1")

so I prefer to attatch 'j'

> jElement = $("#div1")
>
> element = document.elementByID("div1")

Comment: I prefer to use '$': `var $div = $('div')`. But to each his own. :)