# Why is my function called two times?

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
 doSomething(1);    
 $('#pp').click( doSomething(2) );//why is this called?? I didn't click the button..
});

function doSomething(v) {
 alert(v);
}
</script>

<body>

<input type="button" id="pp" value="asdf" />
```

I need a function to be called on load and click. But somehow `doSomething()` is called two times on load. What's going on..??

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316158/jquery-how-do-you-pass-this-as-function-parameter/2316194#2316194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ready fragment to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  doSomething(1);
  $('#pp').click(function() {
    doSomething(2);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 doSomething(1);    
 $('#pp').click( function(){doSomething(2);} );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap what you pass to `.click()` in a `function {}`. Otherwise it executes when the `.click()` line executes and the *result* is passed to `.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an error in your event-binding. It should be:

```
$('#pp').bind('click', function () { doSomething(2); });
```